# Package imported and not used in JSON parser

Tags: json, linux, go

I am currently learning Golang and I jumped into the issue with following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    json, err := ioutil.ReadFile("gopher.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(json, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

I receive this error when I issue `go run main.go`

```
./main.go:7:5: imported and not used: "encoding/json"
./main.go:18:16: json.Unmarshal undefined (type []byte has no field or method Unmarshal)
```

So I wonder what could be the problem, I even tried importing `json encoding/json` and it still seems that this import is not taken into the account. So any ideas? I have a version 1.12.4 instaled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`json, err := ioutil.ReadFile("gopher.json")` defines `json` as variable which overrides `json` package in that scope.

Try this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    jsonFile, err := ioutil.ReadFile("gopher.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file")
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    var dat map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(jsonFile, &dat); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dat)
}
```

Comment: This is really unbelievable, how could I missed that... thank you