# Vs code shows import error in golang code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have go code which looks like this

```
package services

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/config"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/middleware"
    "github.com/supabase/postgrest-go"
)


func GetAllUsers(env *config.Env, db *postgrest.Client, group *gin.RouterGroup) {
    group.GET("/:services", func (router *gin.Context) {
        services := strings.Split(router.Param("service"), ",")
        user, exists := router.Get("user")
        if !exists {
            router.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "user information not found in context"})
            return
        }
        userToken, exists := user.(*middleware.UserToken)
        if exists {
            workspaceId := userToken.User.WorkspaceID
        }

        
        
        
    })
}
```

Here VS code complains about

```
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/middleware"
```

imported but not used error.

which I am using here

```
*middleware.UserToken
```

Here is how my middleware looks

```
package middleware

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/domain"
)




type UserToken struct {
    jwt.StandardClaims
    User domain.UserToken
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error when running `go build`? (if so edit your question and add details).

Comment: @Brits no error when I do `go run main.go`

Comment: Have you tried ```Ctrl + Shift + p ``` > Developer: Reload window. Sometimes VS code fails to index the code properly. See this answer:  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023129/module-lookup-disabled-by-goproxy-off-but-go-env-shows-goproxy-is-set/73049786#73049786]

Comment: @ABDULLOKHMUKHAMMADJONOV Yap

Comment: Note: The `workspaceId` variable is defined inside an `if` block, which means it won't be accessible outside the block. To fix this, declare the variable before the `if` statement. And use `=`, not `:=` for the assignment.

Comment: please see this if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924749/import-and-not-used-error

Answer (score 0):

The repository `github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin` seems to be a private one, which could have that kind of side effect.

Try and add in your VSCode preferences "Go tools env vars":

```json
{
  "go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GOPRIVATE": "github.com/*"
  }
}
```

---

Also, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59770846/6309), check if you have defined elsewhere a variable (or global variable) named `middleware`, which would override the package `middleware`.

Comment: Wouldn't `github.com/*` apply for every project on GitHub? Surely, one would want to scope it to just the username or repository in question.

Comment: @TylerKropp I agree. I was suggesting that as a test. If it works, then we can test a more previse value.

Answer (score -2):

My argument is in favor of VS Code check that we are not "using" the middleware import.

By using, it most probably means "Actually using something from that package". e.g., the `UserToken` struct. Here we are not actually using it, we are just assigning its type to variables which in turns are unused. Apparently, we're using `middleware.UserToken`, but not really, nowhere in that function are we are creating a `UserToken` struct.

```golang
userToken, exists := user.(*middleware.UserToken) 
// Use userToken here
if exists {
      workspaceId := userToken.User.WorkspaceID
}
```

*Merely assigning a type to a variable is not "using" that type.* To fix the warning, we need to actually use something from the middleware package: construct a `UserToken` struct instance.

```golang
// This is an actual usage
userToken := middleware.UserToken{User: domain.UserToken{WorkspaceID: workspaceId}}
```

And now the warning will go away, because we're actually using `middleware.UserToken`.

Comment: The meaning of "using" something from a package is not a matter of opinion. It's a behavior mandated by the [language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Import_declarations): *It is illegal for a package [...] to directly import a package without referring to any of its exported identifiers.*